# AWS SQS Sink in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to add Aws SQS sink in Flink. Wanted to know if anybody has already tried the same or if there is any known challenges with this integration?

Any code references or documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a AWS implementation of a SQS Sink on their 'aws-samples' Github's repository.

Check it out: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-data-analytics-examples/tree/master/SQSSink